# How do I install Windows with Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I am using El Capitan on a 15" MacBook Pro mid 2015. I downloaded a Windows 10 iso file from the Microsoft website.

Then I used Boot Camp Assistant and selected the file. I allocated 120 GB to the Windows partition. It did it's thing and then restarted automatically. It booted back to OSX.

When I look at About This Mac, I see the Bootcamp partition.

If I hold the option button while the Macbook reboots, it only shows me my Mac OS partition.

Did something go wrong? It's like Windows 10 didn't install.. what should I do from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Camp Assistant is a glorified partitioner. It doesn't do any actual installation of anything. For that, you'll have to actually launch the Windows installer from the ISO, by burning it to a disk first, and booting off of that.

Comment: I see, but why did I have to select the Windows 10 iso when using Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: The latest version of Boot Camp Assistant actually allows you to install Windows without burning the ISO do a disk (it still hast to restart to star the actual installation. It doesn't actually install anything), but only on supported computers. I just checked, and your model is supposed to support that, which is probably why it had you select the ISO... As to why it didn't work? Well, I suppose you could try again. You can reference this news posting for more info: http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/30/el-cap-boot-camp-no-usb/

Comment: I redid the whole thing with Boot Camp Assistant and it worked - but unfortunately it halved my drive instead of using what I specified. So now my Windows drive is 220GB rather than 120GB..

Comment: @GreenRails looks like Apple has some work to do to make the process a bit more reliable...